# Regarding the [java-date] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Just today when trying to edit an answer I've come across the [java-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-date) tag.

As you can just tag a question with the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) tags I don't really see why such a tag was created in the first place.

Also the case that it would refer the in Java 8 introduced `java.time` API is defeated, because we already have a [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time) tag.

Then when looking at the tag info I saw:

[image: missing tag wiki]

Oh yeah, there is none. Also that it has 1 watcher and just 86 questions makes me think: is this tag or should it even be used?

So, I am not asking to burninate it but maybe just a retag to [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date)?

Or should we not even bother?

Comment: Retag them, the offensive tag should self-destruct after that.

Comment: Could it be the case that [tag:java] [tag:date] means generic date questions in Java, while [tag:java-date] is specifically the (now deprecated) `java.util.Date` system?

Comment: @OrangeDog Maybe that was the intention, but I don't think it makes sense to have a tag for a single Java class (even if the subject includes a few related classes). We don't have a tag [java-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-string) for `java.lang.String` either.

Comment: Oh for goddess name, date is not a freaking programming tag! If there's a problem I don't want date to be a tag, tags are not #hashtags!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [java-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-date) tag has been cleaned up, and been synonymised with the [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) tag by a moderator.