# Why is there a java-api tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

#### Note: This tag has been synonymized with the Java tag by a moderator.  Nothing more to see here.

---

I've stumbled upon the [java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-api) tag, and I am not sure how it is different to the already widely used [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag?

From the [tag-info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-api/info):

> Java api provides way of using java sdk tools to build java applications.

which seems redundant when also tagging questions with the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. It was created *11 years* ago but hasn't gained any real attention since then: currently only 428 questions have been tagged with it.

What is the community view on this, and what further action should I (or we) take?

Comment: My first question is "Is the existence of the tag actually a problem?" - If not, what's the harm?

Comment: Useless tags are noise.  Noise is harm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I figured out why the [java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-api) tag exists, or at least one reason. I perused the questions with that tag and I saw several that were primarily about technologies other than Java, for example, Elasticsearch. That's a language-independent technology that has APIs for different languages -- language bindings -- including Java, JavaScript, Go, .NET, etc.

In other words, the [java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-api) tag is not about the APIs of Java and the JDK, but it is about the Java API bindings for other technologies such as Elasticsearch.

To pick another example, suppose you're using MongoDB and are writing in Java. You might run into a problem with the MongoDB driver for Java and want to ask a Stack Overflow question about it. You'd tag your question with [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) since that's what you're using, and you might also add the [java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-api) tag since you're using MongoDB's Java binding.

This is pretty subtle. I don't know if it's the best use of Stack Overflow tagging, or if there's some better combination tags that would express this more precisely. I do think it's confusing, as there are a bunch of questions about Java's APIs themselves (that is, the JDK) mixed in there.

We might try to tune up the tag's definition. Or we could just get rid of it and make it a synonym.

**UPDATE 2020-05-03**

I've done a bit more research and discovered that the "meta-tag" approach of using [java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-api) to tag questions about the Java language API binding for some cross-platform technology isn't used anywhere else as far as I can tell. Instead, there are technology-specific tags that also have "java" (or whatever language) in the name, to indicate a language/environment binding for that technology.

I took a quick look at other technologies' tags and I found these related tags for them:

- Elasticsearch: [elasticsearch-dsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-dsl), [elasticsearch-painless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-painless), [elasticsearch-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-net), [elasticsearch-py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-py), [elasticsearch-jdbc-river](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jdbc-river), [elasticsearch-java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-java-api)
- MongoDB: [pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pymongo), [mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoid), [mongodb-.net-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-.net-driver), [mongodb-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-java), [mongodb-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-php)
- MySQL: [mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli), [mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-python), [pymysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pymysql), [node-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-mysql), [rmysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rmysql), [mysql-connector-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-connector-python), [mysqlnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqlnd)

I suspect that most cross-platform technologies follow a similar pattern and have "sub-tags" for drivers or bindings for working with different platforms, languages, or environments.

There aren't very many [java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-api) questions to begin with, and only some of them are tagged this way. Its remaining use seems to be an attractor for random questions about the Java Platform APIs. This isn't useful, as there are already a bunch of java-related tags.

As such, [java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-api) no longer serves any useful purpose, and I now agree with [Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397001/1441122) that the [java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-api) tag can be synonymized with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer, I am sorry that I did not reply earlier. Also, it seems that the tag was synonymized into java now, I suspect by Bhargav Rao. They completed my other question about [java-date](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371655/regarding-the-java-date-tag) too.

Answer (score 7):

This tag is... *weird*.

Maybe a handful of questions read in the context of, "I want an API-backed solution to this approach", but...I don't see why the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag couldn't be used over this one.

My vote:  let's synonymize java-api with java.  I don't think there's going to be a lot of benefit in exhuming or burninating this tag when in reality, the questions are still related to Java.

Comment: That's what I thought too, seems to be the best idea to synonymize it. I haven't looked over all questions though. But it seems to mostly talk about the use of the sdk and generally about the use of the language

Comment: @Lino: At this point I think I can claim 10 years of experience in Java...and if I'm going cross-eyed over why this distinction exists at all, *maybe* it shouldn't?

Comment: See [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397149/1441122). I don't necessarily disagree with you, but I think I figured out an explanation.

Comment: Isn't the Google vs Oracle legal battle over the Java API? Maybe the tag could be re-purposed to non-JVM systems which use the Java API.

Comment: @Makoto I did some more research, and I agree with you now.

Comment: It seems that one of the mods has synonymized the java-api tag with java. So this has been resolved.